# How to send desktop screen to Android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a remote desktop application where the client is an Android tablet. The server is written in Java. I'm able to use the mouse and keyboard over Wi-Fi, but now I'm having problems trying to view my desktop on the tablet. Here's the codes of my server capture:

```
public void screenCap() {
    Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(lastXpos, lastYpos, 500, 500);
    img = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
}

public BufferedImage getScreenCap() {
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Have You checked out http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer ? I've recently checked it on 3.2 and 4.0 and it has worked fine for me.

Comment: i already see that sir but i cant see the codes..

Comment: [source](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Feclipse_projects%2FandroidVNC%253Fstate%253Dclosed),  "source" button at the top, then "browse".

Answer (score 0):

**Android VNC Viewer** is an Open Source project and you can see all the codes [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/source/browse/#svn/tags/v0_5_0/androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC).

Also, feel free to experiment with the different versions of the project listed there.

Comment: No, my friend. Not yet. But even I am planning to and the codes given there are a great way to start your project.

Comment: @JayDiocampo : No my friend. And no need to call me "sir". :)

Comment: oh sorry friend just tell your yahoo mail ., i'll messge you